# Backbone and Session storage

Tags: backbone.js, session-storage

How to fetch data from a Url(json file) and save the changes of the model by using session storage in the same application?

Is this possible? can someone help me in finding a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have a look at these projects on GitHub:

- [Backbone.localStorage](https://github.com/jeromegn/Backbone.localStorage)
- [Backbone.DOMStorage](https://github.com/mikeedwards/Backbone.DOMStorage) (extends the first one with sessionStorage)
- [backbone-session](https://github.com/makesites/backbone-session)

Then you just need to override Backbone collection's `fetch` method to update data from your remote source when needed.

Comment: Thank You. I tried with backbone dual storage plugin similar to backbone-session. Both fits my scenario.

Comment: Glad to help! Don't hesitate to upvote my answer :o)